# Low-res texture blurry

Tags: texturing, uv, image

I unwrapped a simple plane and applied the following 80x80 pixel picture:

[image]

Yes, it's quite small. The problem is, the result is all blurry, like so:

[image]

How do I make it accurate to the pixel?

Comment: Cycles or blender internal render engine? By tiling the image a couple of times in both U an V direction would get the image to it's original resolution on any given polygon surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pixelation**
[image]

Materials, Texture, Image Sampling.
Select all the settings on the right hand side as indicated by the arrow.

MIP Interpolation Filter FELINE Filter Size

Assuming Blender Render.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Blender Internal Render Engine:
In the *Properties Window > Texture Tab > Image Sampling Panel > Filter*
change it to *Box*.

Have in mind that this will not have any effect in the viewport preview, but it won't appear blurry in your final render.

If you are in Cycles/EEVEE Render Engine:
In the *Node Editor*, under your material node tree navigate to your image texture node and set the second pull-down menu *Interpolation* to *Closest*

Answer (score 2):

Using Blender Render, go into the Materials/Texture//Image Sampling and deactivate the Interpolation checkbox.

For the Filter you probably want Box, FELINE, or Area.  I'm not sure exactly what the algorithms behind them are, but the results from EWA are not even remotely sharp.  They only differ when a rendered pixel is on the boundary between two pixels of the texture.