# How to not distort pixels?

Tags: texturing, uv, pixel-art

I am working on a low poly model and I would like to texture it with pixelart. The problem is that whenever I aply the textures, most of the pixels get distorted, stretched or compressed. Is there any way that I could get something like this?

[image: 1]]
[image: 2]]

Currently I am using this model that I made:
https://skfb.ly/PyuC

Comment: The top picture is rendered in _Orthographic View_.

Comment: Most likely because you modified the shape of the UVs.

Answer (score 1):

The question about blurry textures has been asked countless times before, it has to do with the used texture sampling.
See this answer for more details https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47643/19307

As for distorted (as in stretched or compressed) textures it all as to do with the way you UVMap your textures.

Fix your UV's so as not to cause distortions, evenly scaled islands and proportionally unwrapped faces will help. If possible use the *UV Map > Cube Projection* which will cause minimal distortion, or *UV Map > Project From view*

Alternatively consider using generated texture coordinates where possible instead. This may not work in the viewport or exported models.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are rendering in *Perspective View*, rather than *Orthographic View*, which is what is shown in the top image. When you look at something in real life that contains parallel lines, you can notice that they don't look parallel, but like they will intersect. Consider this image of train tracks:

[image]

This is how your police car looks. The truck is rendered in *Orthographic*, where parallel lines look parallel. Consider the same tracks in *Orthographic View*:

[image]

*Above images from the [Blender Reference Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/types/camera/lens.html?highlight=perspective)*

To render in *Orthographic*, select the camera and go to the *Properties panel > Camera Object data tab > Lens dropdown* and click on *Orthographic*.

[image]