# UV mapping perfect pixel textures

Tags: texturing, uv

**I am trying to model a Mech in a very simplistic style with pixelated textures.**
I am trying to achieve something similar to this:

[image]

Here are the textures from the last one:[image: texture]

**Im having issues with the UV mapping**.I am trying to make my mech have similar textures in that way that they are pixelated,straight and perfect.The mech here has a texture size of 128,but im trying with 256.

I have tried with the lightmap pack unwrapping and with smart UV mapping and both make most of the UV straight but they make them distorted at places and not pixel perfect.
The ideal solution would be if somehow all the UVs of the faces could be laying on the normal of the face without any distortion,that way all the pixel would be perfect squares.
I have pixel snapping on and with that still some UV faces arent rotated perfectly straight so the pixels go at a angle.
The only idea that comes to my head is to try to UV unwrap everything by hand which would be really tedious...

Comment: See if this is what you need http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47636/low-res-texture-blurry/47643#47643

Comment: I already done that,the issue i am having is with setting up the UV to have all the pixel perfect.
I just thought up of an idea,maybe i could look at a flat surface and try project from view and see how that goes,it should theoretically give me what i need.

Comment: Well you can only have pixel perfect unwraps if your mesh was totally orthogonal and made up of perfectly rectangular or square faces since all pixels are square, and I see your faces are slanted and trapezoidal. You could also use the *UV Image Editor > UVs > Snap to Pixels* option

Comment: Yeah i figured. I've tried with the lightpack and to tweak a bit by myself and smart unwrap with low angle limit and still i got intersecting pixels in places i didn't want so in the end i went with the all done by hand solution. Either way its gonna have intersecting pixels but at least this way i can control it to some degree.
Anyway thanks for the help :D