# UV pixel bleed from pixel snap in Viewport.

Tags: uv, 3d-view

I'm new to Blender and was hoping someone might have an answer to this.

I'm currently working on a model that uses pixel art with low poly models. To do this I make tiles in Photoshop, then pixel snap the UV to the proper position on the edge of where the pixel ends. (I'm using a 256x256 map in this case). When the camera is close to the model in the Viewport the seams all line up properly and there are no artifacts. However, when the camera pulls away from the model there are some artifacts that looks like the Viewport is sampling between the edges of the UV.

I use a 50/50 gray background for tile placement so the edges around the tiles are gray, when the camera pulls away the UV edges will show a gray seam. I have tried many times to realign the seam and align all UV but the only thing that has worked so far is placing a pixel wide border in between each of the tiles. Although this also diminishes the amount of space I have to work with with a redundant pixel border.

Is there some camera or rendering setting that might help resolve the issue?

[image: Viewport Error]
[image: Example of Texture Map]

Comment: That's mipmapping which means usually that border of one pixel wide (often even more) is left on textures to avoid this, see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50023/how-can-i-prevent-seams-from-showing-up-on-objects-using-lower-mipmap-levels

Comment: Probably related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47636/low-res-texture-blurry