# after rendering why I'm getting fuzzy, unclear image, even though I kept 100% resolution and sample 128 , mipmaps is uncheck

Tags: rendering

after rendering why I'm getting fuzzy, unclear image, even though I kept 100% resolution and sample 128 , mipmaps is uncheck

[image]

Comment: Hi. This may help with taking clearer screenshots: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html

Comment: Please don't take photos of your monitor, those are hard to read a unhelpful to diagnose the problem. Could you edit your question and post a screenshot instead?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47636/low-res-texture-blurry/47643 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/how-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated