# How to prevent blurry interpolation when scaling a texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am using gazebo to develop some optical measurement system and I have to get a good proportion for textures in the object. I made a pyramid of 25 x 12.5 mm and unwrapped a texture in order to have 1 square per millimeter, so I made a texture with a resolution of 25 x 200 (doesn't matter the height for unwrap) and using blender I set the position as the images below.
[image]

When I open the object in Gazebo 7 it appears blurred, as the image below. Resolution of the image is 25 x 200 pixels.

[image]
Image width 25 pixel
Object width 25 mm
Final Resolution 1 px//mm.

When I rescale the image for 250 x 2000 pixels (10 times), I get the result I wanted but I don't understand why.

[image]
Image width 250 pixel
Object width 25 mm
Final Resolution 10 px/mm.

As it is possible to count, the height of object has 25 squares in both images, but the first case gets blured. Anyone can help me explaining why this happens?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I looks a lot like some pixel interpolation for low-res textures. That would explain why hi-res textures work fine.

Comment: [How-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/how-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated) and [Low-res-texture-blurry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47636/low-res-texture-blurry?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The problem comes from Gazebo which does linear or some other sort of interpolation on the low res texture instead of using nearest neighbor. Try to find this setting in the Gazebo material options.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, based only on what the texture output looks like in the window, I would look to see if there is any type of texture filter being applied such as Gaussian and the like that is going on somewhere around the texture to uv mapping area.